# Making a sentence to be accepted by scientific world (academic writing)

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-construction, writing

I have an idea regarding when a certain error found (say error-2), then how it could be eliminated. So, I have constructed a sentence as follows: I am using also, as I am now talking the elimination of 2nd error.

> Also, when a boundary segment,derived by the image based method, is
>   lacking for a certain reference gutter segment, and there is an(are)
>   adjacent roof plane(s) which is(are) highly elevated than that
>   reference gutter and edge of the elevated roof is parallel to that
>   reference gutter, then assuming the location of the reference is wrong
>   and there should be a step-edge in between the reference and elevated
>   roof plane, the missing boundary edge for the image based data is
>   created by down projecting the relevant elevated edge.

But, my problem is when I finish my construction, the sentence is *too long*. *So, Now I want to know whether this type of sentences are accepted by the scientific report.*

Actually, for me it is difficult to imagine a way to break this into small sentences as everything is interrelated.

So, I am looking for suggestions to improve my construction to be accepted by the scientific world. thank you,

Answer (score 3):

The long sentence can be reduced to:

> Also, when X1, derived by X2, is X3, and there is Y1 which is Y2, then assuming (that) Z1 and Z2, C1 is created by C2.

We can even reduce it further to:

> Also, when X and Y, then (assuming/under the condition of) Z, (we do) C.

X, Y, and Z are quite heavy (and so is C), it's natural (though unnecessarily) that you'd want to break it down. There are several ways to do so. However, let's assume that we will stick to the given order (i.e. X, Y, Z, and C)--because it's safer when I don't know what the previous paragraph is--here is one possibility to break it down. (I will simply use X, Y, Z, and C, which are enough to make the point of the rephrasing.)

> Also, the case of error-2 is handled. Error-2 happens when X and Y. Under such condition, assuming Z, (we do) C.

The part "Also, the case of error-2 is handled" can be rephrase more neatly, but that would depend on the last sentence in the previous paragraph. Also, you can be more specific about how it is "handled", e.g. "handled in our scope", "handled by our algorithm/system/application/implementation", etc.

Comment: @Damkerng T.: thank you very much for the comments. Do you think that we do not want to break this sentence in to pieces? or is it acceptable its original form?

Comment: Though a sentence that long is not very common in academic papers, I've seen something that long often enough myself. In case that you have writing consulting services there, it's best to check with them.

Answer (score 1):

This is dangerously close to proofreading; nevertheless:

> We are concerned about three conditions:
>
> (a) When a boundary segment derived by the image-based method is lacking for a certain reference gutter segment, and
>
> (b) there is at least one adjacent roof plane which is highly elevated than that reference gutter, and
>
> (c) the edge of the elevated roof is parallel to that reference gutter.
>
> When those three conditions are true, then – assuming the location of the reference is wrong and there should be a step-edge in between the reference and elevated roof plane – the missing boundary edge for the image-based data is created by down projecting the relevant elevated edge.

I've modified the punctuation some, and I've used enumerated bullet statements to get through that complicated part of your original sentence. I think these formatting changes make the overall paragraph easier to read and understand.

> *Actually, for me it is difficult to imagine a way to break this into small sentences as everything is interrelated*.

I agree, which is why I made the changes the way that I did.  In fact, my version is only two sentences, instead of the original one.

From an English perspective, it's worth noting that we have various formatting tools available (such as bullets, dashes, parentheses, hyphens, and colons) to help make a complex sentence more readable. There's more to punctuation than the comma and the period, and sometime these other punctuation marks are crucial when constructing highly-complex sentences.